# Limite de 3000 caracteres en AWS Polly

Tags: python

Mi problema es que Amazon Web Services Polly no permite oraciones con mas de 3000 caracteres y arroja este error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.TextLengthExceededException: An error occurred (TextLengthExceededException) when calling the SynthesizeSpeech operation: Maximum text length has been exceeded
```

Me gustaria una forma de hacer que funcione con mas palabras, el codigo es:

```
import boto3

txt = "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla ..." #Digamos que hay mas de 1500
translate = boto3.client('translate')
result = translate.translate_text(Text=txt,
                                  SourceLanguageCode="en",
                                  TargetLanguageCode="de")
print(f'TranslatedText: {result["TranslatedText"]}')
print(f'SourceLanguageCode: {result["SourceLanguageCode"]}')
print(f'TargetLanguageCode: {result["TargetLanguageCode"]}')
```

Fuente: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-translate-TranslateText.py.html

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente estás usando un endpoint viejo porque ese límite ya lo subieron según la documentación [(fuente)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/limits.html). Esta misma fuente indica los endpoints por zona y más datos sobre cómo consumir esos servicios.

> The size of the input text can be up to 3000 billed characters (6000 total characters). SSML tags are not counted as billed characters.

Además, las indicaciones que dan en el [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/pricing/) darían a entender que debes mandar tus peticiones de a 3000 por vez.

En uno de los enlaces relacionados indican cómo [crear un audio largo](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/asynchronous.html).

Edit: es raro que cites como enlace una documentación de AWS para TRADUCIR, siendo que quieres usar Polly. Deberías fijarte en el test que hay para Polly [aquí](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-polly-polly_wrapper.py.html)

Comment: Asi es, gracias por la correcion (ya cambie el titulo), pero, me refiero al limite en si, tengo mas de 3000 caracteres, me gustaria saber si hay forma de aumentarlo.

Comment: Honestamente no entiendo el enalce que colocaste de https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/asynchronous.html **Que tengo que hacer en especifico?** Solo quitar el "synthesize_speech" de **polly.synthesize_speech(Text=** por uno de lo que dicen ahi?